# Unable to Export Sqlite database from SpecialFolder.ApplicationData to SD Card Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, export, sqlite-net

I am currently developing an app that uses the sqlite-net database. I am trying to copy/export the database to my SD Card. When I run the code I get a **System.NullRefrenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have tried several solutions but I always get the same exception. The issues occurs at the **System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);** Please help.

```
 private void CopyDBButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            var finalPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Mydatabase");
            CopyDatabase(finalPath);
        }

 public static void CopyDatabase(string databasePath)
        {

            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(databasePath);
            var fileCopyName = string.Format("/sdcard/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", System.DateTime.Now);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);
        }
```

Comment: saying you get a Null Ref without telling us which line causes it is not very helpful

Comment: I apoligse. This is my first time asking a question. The error occurs at the "System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);" line

Comment: I don't see what could be null on that line.  Have you tested everything for null?  If you look at the stack trace is the exception happening in your code, or further down in the stack?

Comment: turned out to be an issue with the path address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the path address. I fixed it by checking for the directory first to see if it exists, then I copy the database to the directory in a new/existing file. The issue I have now is that the file saves to phone but not the SD card, but I am just happy that the backup file is finally saving.
Below is the code is used to fix the issue:

```
    private void CopyDBButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Used to find the database in the special folder
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Mydatabase");

        //Used to locate the SD Card path
        string path1 = Path.Combine("/sdcard/", Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

        //Used to save the Database to a byte array
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        //Used to check if the directory exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(path1))
        {
            //Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
            Console.WriteLine("Doesnt Exist");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Does Exist");

            //Used to create the name of the new Database backup file
            var fileCopyName = string.Format(path1 + "/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);

            //Write to the new database backup file
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the two permissions listed below in your manifest file?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have confirmed that the above permissions are correctly being added, please try the code to export data from the app storage onto your SD Card:

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TodoSQLite.db3");
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var fileCopyName = string.Format("/sdcard/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);
        }
```

Comment: My database is stored in the "Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData" folder. But it seems the issue was the path. I tried your solution and still received the error. In my answer i explained how i was able to fix the error. Thank you for your reply.